# Elastic Search Lucene Query by Time in Python

Tags: python, lucene, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am having a hardtime querying `Elastic Search` using `Kibana` and Python `pyes` library.

https://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

I need to get all the data filtered by a certain `field` with the time range.

Let's say I want to get all data by the field `_customer_id` within the time range between `2014-08-17 20:00:00` and `2014-08-17 21:00:00`. This is my start but can't figure out what to do next.

```
import pyes
from pyes.query import FilteredQuery, MatchAllQuery, BoolQuery, TermQuery
conn = pyes.ES(['87.878.787:9200'])

q = TermQuery("@timestamp", "[2014-08-17T20:00:00 TO 2014-08-17T21:00:00]")
results = conn.search(query = q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get it filtered in Kibana, there is a function to show you the query which was used on each panel. You can then work out easily from there how to build up you Python query.

Comment: Just to clarify - it's the little 'i' information icon in the top-right of each panel.